# Answering ought-to-be-closed questions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, vote-to-close

I have been on read-only mode with Stack Overflow up till recently to take up more moderating duties. I saw that for some questions that are ought to be closed (for being duplicates or asking something trivial), there were people giving direct answers to those question, but were told not to answer "ought-to-be-closed" questions.

In one of my answers to an ought-to-be-closed question, another user wrote this:

> Excuse me but..do you know that questions about typos are off-topic here, right? Why answer a clearly off-topic qusstion?

(typo sic)

What are the guidelines on such grounds? Should people allowed to give answers that address the question directly before the question gets closed?

Example posts:

- [C++11 - what does it mean to initialize a variable to a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933987/c11-what-does-it-mean-to-initialize-a-variable-to-a-reference)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875120/inline-javascript-in-a-function/37875262#37875262
- [Is it a good practice to throw exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336192/is-it-a-good-practice-to-throw-exceptions/37336288#37336288)

*Note that this is different from answering closed questions.*

Comment: Well if a question should be closed, you see it, and then you still put an answer in, I think you shouldn't do it, because there is a reason why the question gets closed.

Comment: thanks @gnat for the heads up. didn't find that question with my searches.

Comment: Are you posting this because of the serial downvotes you've been receiving since you posted that answer?

Comment: @BoltClock hey BoltClock, nope. It's more of the comment I've gotten that I quote in this question. Seems like SO has changed so much.